# NoSuchMethodError for driver using methods defined for classes in same folder

Tags: java, eclipse, nosuchmethoderror

I know that other people have gotten the same error, but I was having a hard time finding anything useful to solving my problem in past answers.  I'm trying to implement some basic Stack and Queue classes I built for my data structures class, and I've built two driver methods that are running into the same problem.  They can instantiate members of the classes fine and everything compiles well both in Eclipse and on the command line, but when I try to use the push(CharNode) or enqueue(CharNode) methods (with CharNode being another class I created that has pretty typical node qualities), I get the following error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Stack.push(LCharNode;)V"

I was looking at past answers to see what was going wrong, and I don't think the Classpath changed between compile time and runtime (or at least I didn't change it - I'm trying to run this immediately after compiling), and I don't think it could be an issue of not having the right library because all of these classes are in the same src folder.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

Here's the code for my CharNode, Stack, and StackTest classes:
CharNode:

```
public class CharNode {
private char name;
private CharNode nextNode;

public CharNode(char data, CharNode insert){
    name = data;
    nextNode = insert;
}

public void setData(char newData){
    name = newData;
}

public char getData(){
    return name;
}

public void setNextNode(CharNode link){
    nextNode = link;
}

public CharNode getNextNode(){
    return nextNode;
} 
}
```

Stack:
    public class Stack {

```
private CharNode top;

public Stack(){
    top = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    if (top == null) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void push(CharNode newLink){
    if (isEmpty()){
        top = newLink;
    }
    else {
        newLink.setNextNode(top);
        top = newLink;
    }
}

public CharNode pop(){
    if (isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    else {
        CharNode value = top;
        top = top.getNextNode();
        return value;
    }
} 
}
```

StackTest:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Stacktest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Stack newStack = new Stack();
        CharNode newNode = new CharNode('c', null);
        System.out.print("We got this far 1 \n");
        newStack.push(newNode);
        System.out.print("We got this far 2 \n");
    }
}
```

It looks like other people aren't having problems with this, but the output when I try to run it is: "Exception in thread "main" We got this far 1 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Stack.push(LCharNode;)V
    at Stacktest.main(Stacktest.java:9)" 
(Don't have the reputation to post screenshots.)

I don't think it's trying to implement a different Stack, since when I check the method signatures using the Refactor tool, they're the same for where I define them and where I try to use them.

Comment: You need to paste some code. It could literally be anything.

Comment: It's very possible you have another `Stack` class you define somewhere accessible, that doesn't have a `push` method. I've seen this problem a few times here before.

Comment: I get no errors or exceptions running this code.

Comment: Just for fun, rename your Stack class to rule out that you aren't importing a different Stack class than you think you are (as peeskillet suggested may be the case). Call it MyStack or something that is not likely to clash with any other classes in any other JARs you're using.

Comment: Agree with peeskillet. I ran the code in Eclipse as-is and it ran fine.

Comment: J Steven Perry, I renamed followed your advice and it seems to have worked.  Thanks!